# Fiddler - Xamarin Forms - Local Azure Backend - iOS simulator

Tags: proxy, ios-simulator, xamarin.forms, fiddler

I've got:

- a PC and mac linked through Xamarin in VS2015
- fiddler running on the PC
- a local azure backend running on the pc
- the mac http proxy is setup to fiddler ip (my pc ip) and port (8888)

I'm debugging a Xamarin Forms app on Xamarin iOS Simulator on PC.

When I browse in safari within Xamarin iOS Simulator, Fiddler captures it. However, when my app makes some requests to my local backend (HTTP not HTTPS) I don't see them. If I run the app in a Windows simulator, the requests are captured.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now use Fiddler with Azure mobile app, Xamarin and ios tks to @user6581605 as well as this post:
https://shellmonger.com/2016/06/23/using-modernhttpclient-with-azure-mobile-apps/

I installed the modernhttpclient nuget from [Paul Betts](https://twitter.com/paulcbetts) :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/

Then I instanciate my MobilerServiceClient this way:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://mysite.azurewebsites.net",
    new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler());
```

To finish update info.plist with

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
       </dict>
  </dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but creating a proxy class as Felix Collins answers in the next post help me.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24411/how-can-i-inspect-my-xamarin-forms-apps-network-traffic

I hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was an immense help